# How can ISPs on one continent connect to ISPs on another continent?

Tags: cisco

How can ISPs on one continent connect to ISPs on another continent? From a physical layer standpoint? Say one ISP is located in Asia and another one in Europe how would they connect their fiber optic cable to exchange traffic? Also how would they connect physically through IXP (Internet Exchange Points) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_exchange_points_by_size Do they have to drag their fiber optics cable all the way to these locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISPs come in multiple sizes and smaller ones simply get their internet connectivity from bigger ones (to read more on that start with [peering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peering) and transit). E.g. if you are a customer of a regional ISP then that gets its uplink from a national ISP, which in turn has connections with several other national and international networks.

Every layer of this nested structure is responsible for its physical cables: The regional ISP has to lay fiber/copper to the national ISP's data center. And the national ISP has to find a way to connect to all its network peers. -- This is where the IXPs come in as a "meeting point" for multiple networks.

Finally most intercontinental connections are by undersea cables, see http://www.cablemap.info/ for a nice map.

Answer (score 4):

There are long-haul fiber (and copper) cables all over the world (over land and under oceans). There are also satellite links and terrestrial wireless  networks. The bits have to flow over some media. That doesn't mean that a provider needs to own the media, however. Many ISPs lease access to media when it isn't economical or feasible to use media they own. This can create the interesting paradox of supposedly "redundant" connections via different ISPs that, physically, end up running over the same media. There have been cable cuts that knocked out entire regions' Internet access because, although there were multiple ISPs, they all ended up leasing space on the same physical cable.